# Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbtk.class

When I run our android studio project these errors come up. How could I solve them?

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shikshamela.shikshamela"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'


    })


    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: too old question .show your `build.gradle`

Comment: remove your `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'` line and try to complie

Answer (score 0):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shikshamela.shikshamela"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'


    })




       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'              
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: under /libs directory do you have some .jar files like support-v4?

Comment: use `10.2.1` instead of `10.0.1` .

Comment: Remove this post and add this question section

Answer (score 0):

```
// copy paste below code

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'


        })


        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
   > Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:25.3.1.
     
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:25.3.1.
     
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:25.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:25.3.1.
    
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:25.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app

Answer (score 0):

try this change

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

To

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make dependent jars compatible, so update these two latest version.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

Update to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
```